# Read hidden field values from another page

Tags: asp.net, hidden-field

I am developing a website using ASP.net.

In my home page I have 14 tree view controls. They were placed under Jquery tabs. So when a user click a tab it only appears one treeview. So in tree node changed event currently what I am doing is passing the values from query string to another page. this query string doesnt have any sensitive data. I have to pass what is the selected Tab Id and selected tree node Id.

```
Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/Display.aspx?tab=1&type={0}",treeview1.SelectedValue), true);
```

But you know URL is ugly. I dont want to use Friendly URL thing now. 
So what I did was I put 2 hidden fields values in my home page and I set them when I click the tree node.

So then from the source page I used this code to acess this.

```
 if(Page.PreviousPage!=null)
                {
                    string tab= Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("hftab").UniqueID;
                    string Type= Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("hfType").UniqueID;
                }
```

But Page.PreviousPage always return NULL. So how to solve this probelem without using sessions and query string. I just want to pass two non sensitive data behind the scenes.

IF this is about Cross page postback thing How to do this cross page post back in node change event? Is it ok to do a Cross page post back for to get only 2 values that I needed?

Answer (score 0):

The method you are trying is only possible with "Cross page posting" mechanism. When you set PostbackUrl property of a server control like button, and set the PreviousPage property of Page directive on destination page; then only you will get Page.PreviousPage values.

Here are some reference:
1. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/604553/Postback-and-Cross-Page-Posting-in-ASP-NET
2. http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/05/cross-page-post-backing-in-net.html

Comment: How to do this cross page post back in node change event? Is it ok to do a Cross page post back for to get only 2 values that I needed?

Comment: If your intention is not to expose the IDs in query string then why not to use session variables and remove then as long as you received it on the second page.